# Modelviewer environment of three.js editor in react-three-fiber

Tags: three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber

I'm working on a little project with react-three-fiber. If I load my .gbl 3D Model into the scene it's completly dark even if I use the ambientlight in the canvas. But in the three.js editor it looks exactly like I want it if I use the Modeviewer environment. Is it possbile to download this environmet somewhere and use it in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, the stage component from the drei library https://twitter.com/0xca0a/status/1402975317174726656 all you need is wrap your model into `<Stage>`. as for models being dark even with ambientlight, this is usually related to wrong materials, for instance metalness=1. take a look here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/ambient-light-and-gltf-models-not-working-results-in-black-model/7428/5